# Integral of Brownian Motion w.r.t Time: what is wrong with this solution?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic

My question is about a stochastic integral of brownian motion w.r.t time.

Let $W(t)$ the Wiener process (or brownian motion). I want to calculate this:
\begin{eqnarray}
X(t)=\int_{0}^t dt' W(t').
\end{eqnarray} 
My strategy:

1) Itô's Fórmula:
\begin{eqnarray}
d(tW(t))=tdW(t)+W(t)dt \implies W(t)dt=d(tW(t))-tdW(t).
\end{eqnarray}
2) Integrate:
\begin{eqnarray}
X(t)=\int_{0}^t dt'W(t')=\int_0^t d(t'W(t'))+\int_{0}^tdW(t')t'=tW(t)-\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}W(t)=\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)tW(t).
\end{eqnarray}
I used:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^t dW(t')f(t')=\left(\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^t dt'|f(t')|^2\right)^{1/2}W(t)\implies \int_0^t dW(t')t'=\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}W(t),
\end{eqnarray}
because...
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^t dW(t')f(t')\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\int_0^t dt'|f(t')|^2\right), \hspace{0.5cm} W(t)\sim \mathcal{N}(0,t).
\end{eqnarray}

The "problem" is:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma^2_X=\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2 t^3
\end{eqnarray}
But the correct is:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma^2_X=\frac{t^3}{3} 
\end{eqnarray}
Can some illuminated mind tell me where the error is?

Comment: This is one of the most common introductory problems and has been answered multiple times before. Please spend a bit of time searching for existing questions before opening a new question.

Comment: My question is about a proposed solution to the problem and what is wrong with it. It is not a duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let me know if any of the steps is not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much. Quite clear. But I can not see what is wrong with my solution. If you can help me I'm very grateful.

Comment: Your approach ignores the covar between the components, I think

Answer (score 0):

Re-comment and your second question as to why your transformation leads to a different result, it is because the transformation does not take into account the covariance between the two terms. As you can see below, the covaraince is distorted;

[image]

Comment: Yes! $\int_0^t d(t'W(t'))-\int_0^t dW(t')t'\neq tW(t)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}W(t)$.